# uncheck all check boxes other then one when clicked on a particular checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Say I have three checkboxes if I check the "No Entry" checkbox other checkboxes should be unchecked if they are checked. If I check on other checkboxes when "No Entry" is checked, "No Entry" should be unchecked. I am trying to implement this using Javascript and jQuery.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="otherCheckboxes" id="checkbox1" value="1" /> 1
<input type="checkbox" class="otherCheckboxes"  id="checkbox2" value="2" /> 2
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="No Entry" /> No Entry
```

I have tried this but it's not functioning according to the above requirement.

```
$('#checkbox3').click(function() {
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.otherCheckboxes').attr('checked', false);
}
```

Comment: If you want other checkboxes to be disabled, then just making check property to false won't be enough. Try setting disabled to true. Then again if other checkboxes gets disabled then user will have to uncheck the no entry first to select other checkboxs. That will add one extra click which might not be a good idea.

Comment: @Badhon can you please provide an example in jQuery. I am new to work with front end framework. Hence it is making it difficult for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```js
var otherCheckboxes = $('.otherCheckboxes');
var noEntry = $('#checkbox3');
otherCheckboxes.on('change', function(e) {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
     noEntry.prop('checked', false);
    };
}).trigger('change');
noEntry.on('change', function(e) {
    if( noEntry.is(':checked') ) {
     otherCheckboxes.prop('checked', false);
    };
}).trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <label for="checkbox1"><input type="checkbox" class="otherCheckboxes" id="checkbox1" value="1" /> 1</label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="checkbox2"><input type="checkbox" class="otherCheckboxes"  id="checkbox2" value="2" /> 2</label>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="checkbox3"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" value="No Entry" /> No Entry</label>
</p>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5307tjr/).

Comment: This is Exactly what i am looking for. Thanks a lot. @skobalijic

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#checkbox3').change(function() {
if (this.checked) {
    $('.otherCheckboxes').each(function(){
        this.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. But its not working when i try to implement this. .click function is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click change',function() {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) { //if ($(this).is(':checked')) { will do too
        if ($(this).hasClass('otherCheckboxes')) {
            $('#checkbox3').prop('checked',false);
        } else {
            $(this).siblings().prop('checked',false);
        }
    }
});
```

Or:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('click change',function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var uncheck = $(this).hasClass('otherCheckboxes')?$('#checkbox3'):$(this).siblings();
        uncheck.prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.